# Making powerpoints for youtube?

Tags: libreoffice, youtube, microsoft-office, video-recording, microsoft-powerpoint

When I was running windows 10, I was planning on using its powerpoint program to make youtube videos. And yes, it would be sufficient for my needs, and honestly better than a camera. The windows program could record your voice and even output the file in a format that youtube will support. It literally couldn't be easier. Of course, my sshd fried not long after that so I no longer have it on my main computer. Openoffice, the office suit I'm most used to doesn't support any of these features I know. This OS though came with something called Libreoffice which I can't find any info on.

Is there any program that's as convenient as this? I do know ubuntu22 comes with a feature to record videos of your desktop, though I don't know if it could record my voice or if the video is in the fileformat for youtube (I don't actually know the name of the file types it will accept).

Its not desperately necessary, to be clear. I still have a windows 10 laptop, but it runs so slow I would prefer to not bother with it. I was thinking of recording stuff on this thing and then transferring the files to the laptop to use in its powerpoint program, but that would still be quite a hassle.

Comment: Try using Impress in the LibreOffice suite which is built-in in Ubuntu. Impress has a lot of good features. If you have any specific questions about using LibreOffice Impress please post them as another question to prevent this question from becoming too broad.

Answer (score 0):

In summary, probably there is no program that is equally convenient as Powerpoint that can create a very good quality screencast with recording from a single application.

For the single time I used Powerpoint to create a movie of a photo slide, it was impressively easy and adequate, indeed. Unfortunately, LibreOffice Impress does not have the capability to record a sound track along with a presentation, and directly write out to video. It also continues to lag behind with respect to the quality and fluidity of presentation effects and transitions.

Still, it is not much more difficult to create a screencast using open source software, but you need to rely on different tools. Once the presentation is finished, you will need to rely on screen recording during play back, during which you also can record the audio.Screen recording tools include Kooha, vokoscreen or, of course, the excellent OBS studio. With all three, you also can immediately do the audio recording.

Comment: Maybe I just need to keep a windows laptop so I can use its tools then, and stick to linux for gaming and everything else.